# Simply adding to SSH known_host without forcing an error?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have two machines `devbox`, and `gitbox`. The second machine, `gitbox` is a development box that has no shell, and is *very* locked down just to afford git over ssh (there isn't access to `/bin/true` even)

What I want to do is add to `devbox`'s `.ssh/known_hosts` the entry for `gitbox`. Currently what I do is,

```
ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no git.server.com __NOOP__
```

This does what I want, but it has to attempt to run `__NOOP__`, ideally I would like to **just** add to the `known_hosts` file.

Is there a method of doing this?

Comment: `ssh -N git.server.com` then Control-C. Or `ssh -s git.server.com no_such_subsystem`.

Comment: Running something doesn't exist such as a `__NOOP__` or `no_such_subsystem` is what I'm trying not to do, and the ^C won't work as i'm doing this in a script.

Comment: A sshd subsystem is **not** run as a separate command. Look up the -s option in the manpage. You can also do a remote forwarding guaranteed to fail with -N: ssh -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -N -R 80:localhost:8880 (if not running as root on the remote machine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ssh-keyscan , then append the output to ~/.ssh/known_hosts

```
ssh-keyscan git.server.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: never used `-keyscan` I'll check it out when I get back to the ofc.